# Functional minimization problem

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Is there a smooth solution to minimize this:
$$
\int_0^1{x \over {1+k^2f'(x)^2}}dx, f(0)=1, f(1)=0, f'(x)\leq 0, k^2>0.
$$
I could "solve" it using a numeric approximation (my algorithm converged so apparently there is a valid local minimum in the function space) but would love to see an analytic solution (algebraic or not, doesn't matter). Thank you so much in advance. Fingers crossed.

Comment: I can't tell what the problem is.  If you let $k$ get arbitrarily large, your integrals tend to zero.  So there would appear to be no minimum.

Comment: @RyanBudney: Maybe $k$ is supposed to be fixed?

Comment: $k^2$ is a constant, a form factor.

Comment: Have you tried Euler-La grange equation?

Comment: @ Fan Zheng I did, but it doesn't work (at least not the standard way to use it) because a "zigzag" (going up and down with a small x variation) function would make a very high $f'(x)$ and that would minimize the functional. I don't know how to introduce a monotonic restriction in the Euler-Lagrange method.

Comment: You got the point. By making your function more and more Zigzagging, you can make the integral arbitrarily close to 0. Yet no smooth function will make it exactly 0, so the answer is no.

Comment: @ Fan Zheng Sorry but I don't agree with your conclusion. There is a monotonic restriction (the functional does not evaluate correctly a non monotonic function) and minimizing doesn't mean being exactly 0.

Comment: The integrand is positive and the functional can be made arbitrarily close to zero as you point out. Thus, by a squeezing argument, if there is smooth minimiser. then it is assigned 0 by the functional. However, there clearly isn't one.

I don't understand your comment. Where is this additional "monotonic restriction" coming from. Are you asking to impose it?

Comment: By the way, it also has no smooth maximizer: You can make f drop sharply to 0 sharply and remain 0 thereafter to make the integral arbitrarily close to 1/2. Again no smooth function will make it exactly 1/2. Actually, the EL equation is singular at 0, so there is even no smooth critical point of the functional.

Comment: Also, which exact algorithm converged. There are many subtleties to minmising a functional numerically and often one can't make a conclusion about global optima from numerics. Are you really looking for a minimiser or a stationary curve as this is what the EL equations find.

Comment: I missed the condition $f'\le 0$ ( reading on my phone but not rotating to the right direction). But still I think there is no smooth minimizer. I'll write it up later

Comment: @Benjamin the monotonic is from f'(x)<=0. This equation is the drag from a revolution solid with height/radio = k. This equation was my attempt to calculate drag using gas kinetic theory but long time ago now I know it is only valid at extremely low gas densities (free path >> height and free path >> radius). If the surface does a zig zag then there would be multiple colisions that the equation does not account for (but the equation is fine if the generation function is monotonic).

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't spot that. Have you used a Lagrange multiplyer to impose the constraint?

Comment: No, because I don't know how to do it. Tried to understand how to use Lagrange multipliers with Euler-Lagrange method but got stuck, I am not a mathematician and I am not that smart.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually this is one of the oldest problems in the calculus of variations. It's named "the Newton problem" after Sir Isaac Newton, who studied it in 1685. It arises from the determination of the optimal profile for the motion of bodies (projectiles, ships, etc), that is, the profile giving the minimal aerodynamic or hydrodynamic resistance. Here you are assuming axial symmetry, but the problem is even studied under more general assumptions.

So you can find a lot of material from the keywords "Newton problem" and "Calculus of variations". Here is a nice [survey paper](http://cvgmt.sns.it/media/doc/paper/1339/BUTTAZZO.PDF) by Giuseppe Buttazzo (see in particular section *2* and the references therein for the radial case).

Comment: Dude, would you believe that I was trying to find a solution for this equation for more than 20 years (of course I moved on but always revisiting it)? I read about calculus of variations before but only saw the brachistochrone and  catenary, I feel stupid for not finding the Newton already solved it but I can't google an equation can I? How would I know it was "Newton problem"? (how did you?) Thank you so much, I really wanted to see the solution before I die (I am not dying, at least not as far as I know, well we are all dying, but you know what I mean), many many thanks!!!

Comment: I guess it should be better known than many of the other variational problems.